# Overriding Magento Controller functions

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, controllers

I am overriding the AccountController in a Magento Extension.

In my controller i have the present

```
require_once 'Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php';
```

My question is I am overriding the createPostAction() function inside my controller like so;

```
public function createPostAction() {

//Do stuff

}
```

so do i have to include the original createPostAction() function code found in the Magento **AccountController.php** inside my createPostAction() function or can i just add my additional code inside my createPostAction() function and the override will take in both functions the action is fired?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

copy the complete function createPostAction() code from the core to the controller where you are overriding and make the changes in this function.

overriding means createPostAction will be called from your overriden controller not core if you overridden.

Note:- for more information on how to override createPostAction from accountcontroller.php refer http://magento-online-tutorials.blogspot.in/2015/10/how-to-override-createpost-action-in.html

Comment: Thanks mate! Yep just tested my question and controller action failed so thanks for clearing that up.